# Linux: fast creating of formatted output file (csv) from find command

Tags: linux, format, find

I have several devices, which I want to collect in a list (csv) to put them into a mysql database. I began with a device with the goal to create a new formatted output file, from infile file which was created with 'find'. The device is /mnt/sda4 and I have skipped all entries containing '.cache'. I also have already cut `/mnt/sda4/`:

```
find /mnt/sda4 | grep -v '.cache' | cut -d'/' -f4- > infile
```

where the infile is like that:

```
Extern-500GB-btrfs/root/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/config/soffice.cfg/dbaccess/ui/mysqlnativesettings.ui

Extern-500GB-btrfs/root/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/config/soffice.cfg/dbaccess/ui/namematchingpage.ui
```

...

This part is very fast.

```
real    0m1,432s
user    0m1,079s
sys     0m0,873s
```

Now, I have two solutions, both (very) slow, and I would like to have a new output list with the following of every line processed; "06;" basename ";/" whole line processed, like this:

```
06;mysqlnativesettings.ui;/Extern-500GB-btrfs/root/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/config/soffice.cfg/dbaccess/ui/mysqlnativesettings.ui

06;namematchingpage.ui;/Extern-500GB-btrfs/root/usr/lib64/libreoffice/share/config/soffice.cfg/dbaccess/ui/namematchingpage.ui
...

time while read p; do bn=$(basename "$p"); echo "06;""$bn"";/""$p" >> outfile.csv; done < infile
```

The time need for this, is:

```
real    27m44,937s
user    10m4,539s
sys     18m6,491s
```

I made another try with one command line combining find and formatting the same time:

```
time find /mnt/sda4/ | while read p; do g=$(echo $p | grep -c -v '\.cache'); case "$g" in 1) echo "06;$(basename "$p")"';/'$(cut -d'/' -f4- <<<"$p") >>outfile.csv;; *) : ;; esac; done
```

I forgot the time for this, but it took a long time also.

So, my question is: Is there a (much) faster way to create the second table, maybe directly when working with find?

Thank you in advance,

-Linuxfluesterer

Comment: Sorry, I really have an idea why someone of you members here vote me down. I worked two days to find an elegant solution, but had no success. So, that's why I'm asking here the more experienced people, but I'm sure not to deserve a down vote.

Comment: I'm not sure, either ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess the problem is with the looping and all the redirections; have you considered using awk?  I think the following should do all you need - I obviously don't have your directory structure to test with, though - and be reasonably quick.

```
time find /mnt/sda4/ | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}!/.cache/ {$2=$3=""; new=sprintf("%s",$0);gsub(/^\/\/\//,"",new); printf "06;%s;/%s\n",$NF,new }' > outfile.csv
```

Comment: What an elegant, very fast solution. Great! Thank you very much. This worked within 0m3,137s (user). To answer your question: Yes I have considered (and tried) to work with 'awk', because it is said to be very powerful. The truth is, I haven't understood the structure of the awk command and its using in practice yet. It is too complex (complicated?) for me.
But when I have found a good howto with examples, then I will try again, sure!

Comment: I have tried your solution. Yes it is very fast, but the '.cache' lines are not skipped (I checked now. Then I tested your solution with
.../!'\.cache' (set within ticks and using a backslash for the slash). Still not skipped. To say again: All records with .cache should be skipped, no matter where in the line .cache appears

Comment: Pleased to hear that it worked for you ... if anything is unclear I'm happy to elaborate, I just tend not to go all garrulous from the onset so I don't bore the recipient with too much detail they already know/understand ... the most important thing about awk is that it allows you to work on a stream  - that is, no need for loop processing.

Comment: Ugh, my bad ... when I typed it in the browser is swapped places of two characters ... let me rectify that.

Comment: The `!` belongs in front of the slash.

Comment: Ok, fine now, it really works. I tested with a much bigger device with rsynced backups, so many files have same inodes.
And it took just 0m23,097s (user) time for a 1TB device.

Comment: Das freut mich doch zu hören ;)