# Adapt command to creating csv file from storage content including date(time) & file size also

Tags: linux, awk, find

According to thread:

[Linux: fast creating of formatted output file (csv) from find command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64125084/linux-fast-creating-of-formatted-output-file-csv-from-find-command)

there is a suggested bash command, including awk (which I don't understand):

```
find /mnt/sda2/ | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}!/.cache/ {$2=$3=""; new=sprintf("%s",$0);gsub(/^\/\/\//,"",new); printf "05;%s;/%s\n",$NF,new }' > $p1"Seagate-4TB-S2-BTRFS-1TB-Dateien-Verzeichnisse.csv"
```

With this command, I am able to create a csv file containing "05;file name;full path and file name" of the directory and file content of my device mounted on /mnt/sda2. Thanks again to -> tink

How must I adapt the above command to receive date(&time) and file size also?

Thank you in advance,

-Linuxfluesterer

Comment: Hi, interesting, perhaps use `find ~/ -type f -printf "%p,%A+,%s\n"` The [`printf`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/find.1.html) option can take many format options.

Comment: Thanks, but with this solution I cannot exclude directory entries (I can't do with -type d, then I have no files) with ".cache". I think to solve this, -> tink recommended my to use 'awk'.